# auditd process stops logging after logrotate script runs

Tags: linux, centos6, centos5, logrotate, auditd

I am trying to use logrotate to keep audit logs for a set period of time rather than using auditd's special rotation (from `/etc/audit/auditd.conf`). I have changed the `max_log_file_action` to `IGNORE` in that file.

The following is my logrotate configuration:

```
/var/log/audit/audit.log {
    daily
    dateext
    rotate 180
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/auditd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

The logs are rotated successfully. However, the audit daemon does not start logging again. `/var/log/audit/audit.log` remains empty until I restart the auditd service. I have also tried `/bin/kill -USR1` and `service auditd reload`, but those options do not work well either. `/bin/kill -USR1` actually keeps the audit daemon running, but it creates an empty `audit.log.1` file.

Is there a way to successfully send a signal to the audit daemon to keep it running after logrotate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your kill command is actually failing to kill the process. Try the following:

```
/var/log/audit/audit.log {
    daily
    dateext
    rotate 180
    postrotate
        $(/bin/kill `cat /var/run/auditd.pid 2> /dev/null`)
        service auditd restart
    endscript
}
```

Comment: If you use a service restart, I'd say you don't need to kill the process, right?

Answer (score 1):

Answering this due to a Community bump...

Auditd supports forced rotation via `service auditd rotate` command. You can combine this with a cron to run it based on time. (Daily, hourly, every Tuesday at 10:00 AM, etc.)

An example is included with the RPM at /usr/share/doc/audit-*$version*/auditd.cron.